# How to integrate ABB's PC SDK into Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll

For a project of mine, I need to use a Unity application to communicate with an ABB robot. This can be done through the use of ABB's PC SDK.

Link to the SDK: http://developercenter.robotstudio.com/pcsdk

In a C# project in VS is very simple to implement, but I am struggling a bit with the Unity implementation.

Unity version: (2018.3.8f1)

I have tried to add the .dll files(ABB.Robotics.Controllers.PC / RobotStudio.Services.RobApi.Desktop / RobotStudio.Services.RobApi) in Unity by putting them in the assets folder of the program. When I put the dll's, there were two errors which said that there is no reference to Google.Protobuf and tar-cs. I found the dll's on the Internet and put them into the project. After that no errors appeared.

Then in code I tried:

```
NetworkScanner scanner = new NetworkScanner(); //Scans the network or robot controllers
```

And I got this error.

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
Rethrow as AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].GetResultCore (System.Boolean waitCompletionNotification) (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].get_Result () (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
RobotStudio.Services.RobApi.Desktop.RobPlatformDesktop+<>c.<.cctor>b__2_1 () (at <901697530f6a4ba88a60f7c648717fba>:0)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
Rethrow as AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].GetResultCore (System.Boolean waitCompletionNotification) (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].get_Result () (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
RobotStudio.Services.RobApi.Desktop.RobPlatformDesktop.GetNetscan () (at <901697530f6a4ba88a60f7c648717fba>:0)
RobotStudio.Services.RobApi.Internal.RobApiProviderManager.AddProvider (System.String providerId, RobotStudio.Services.RobApi.Internal.IRobApiProvider provider) (at <8d4f5d48ee63449dbb1112cb5a802708>:0)
RobotStudio.Services.RobApi.Desktop.RobPlatformDesktopInit.Initialize () (at <901697530f6a4ba88a60f7c648717fba>:0)
ABB.Robotics.Controllers.Discovery.NetworkScanner..cctor () (at <e27eeaf9f4444392aac382e4960f38fe>:0)
Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'ABB.Robotics.Controllers.Discovery.NetworkScanner' threw an exception.
ButtonScript.SimpleOutput () (at Assets/ButtonScript.cs:39)
System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (System.Object state) (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state) (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart () (at <d7ac571ca2d04b2f981d0d886fa067cf>:0)
System.Object:__icall_wrapper_mono_generic_class_init()
ButtonScript:SimpleOutput() (at Assets/ButtonScript.cs:39)
System.Threading.ThreadHelper:ThreadStart()
```

I am not sure if the problem is with the method itself or if I did not implement the PC SDK correctly.

My question is there a better way to implement PC SDK into Unity?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that Mono can support ABB's dll